# Datetime columns in sys.dm_db_mirroring_connections are an hour behind

Tags: sql-server-2016, mirroring, dmv

I have database mirroring set up on my SQL Server instance.

If I run `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_mirroring_connections` I get information about the mirroring connections, however, all the time columns in that table (connect_time, login_time, last_activity_time) are all an hour behind what they should be.

For example, `last_activity_time` is currently showing `2019-06-06 15:07:30.444` but the when I do `SELECT GETDATE()` I get `2019-06-06 16:07:48.324` (obviously a few seconds elsapsed between the two) which is the correct time now.

Where does this DMV get it's times from and how can I ensure they use the correct time?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is presently summer time in the Northern hemisphere, it's likely that you're comparing winter time to summer time, which would explain the 1 hour difference.